# dendrogram of cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, hierarchical-clustering

I want the dendrogram of this data:

```
tt =  1.0e+03 *
```

Columns 1 through 5

```
3.8334    3.9707    3.8887    2.1713    2.5616
```

Columns 6 through 7

```
2.3764    2.4533
```

I use the code in matlab:

```
tree = linkage(tt,'average');
figure()
dendrogram(tree)
```

but it gives this error:

> Error using linkage (line 137)

The first input does not appear to be a distance matrix because its size is not compatible with the output of the PDIST function. A data matrix input must have more than one row.

What's the problem
and i want the out put to be intervals.is the dendrogram output intervals?

Comment: at least s.b please tell me can we do something that the output of dendrogram became intervals,numbers like:{{47080, 50280}, {143820, 146820}, {228730, 231330},
               {249560, 252170}, {346060, 349220}, {461740, 463540},
                {546100, 548810}, {646400, 646960}, {690680, 691120}};

Comment: That's the correct code. Just transpose `tt` to make a column vector: `tt'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input to linkage is arranged with rows as observations and columns as variables, but in your example tt is a 1x7 row vector, suggesting a single observation at each of 7 variables. Instead, transpose tt to a column vector if this data represents 7 observations of a single variable, and you can then plot the dendrogram:

```
% your original tt variable
tt = 1.0e+03 .* [3.8334 3.9707 3.8887 2.1713 2.5616 2.3764 2.4533];
% transpose from row vector to column vector
tt = tt';
% proceed as planned
tree = linkage(tt,'average');
figure()
dendrogram(tree)
```

Comment: that works thank you. but yet i've got another question. can you please answer me. i want the output of this dendrogram be intervals. i really do not know why but i'm working on an article which it's result after performing dendrogram on them is intervals. is it possible or i'm wrong and that is not possible

Comment: I'm not sure, what do the intervals represent? Confidence intervals?

Comment: they are audio and video clusters. for example for video this kind of things should be done:"The video stream is segmented into shots based on color histograms
to detect abrupt changes and progressive transitions. Each
of the resulting shot is summarized by a key frame, taken in the middle
of the shot, in turn represented as a RGB histogram with 8 bins
per color. Bottom-up clustering relies on the Euclidean distance between the 512-dimension color histograms using Ward’s linkage" i saw the result which are intervals like:{{47080, 50280}, {143820, 146820}, {228730, 231330}, {249560, 252170}}